# Как сделать так, чтобы бот в дискорде не мог мутить выше стоящую роль?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Условно, у нас есть модератор и я хочу сделать так, чтобы этот модератор не смог замутить админа, роль которого стоит выше него. и так же, если роль бота стоит ниже роли админа, то бот ничего не смог сделать админу

Comment: создайте отдельный вопрос про команду clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, как вариант, вот:

```py
@bot.command(name='мьют', pass_context=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
       bot.say('Нельзя мутить админов! плохой мальчик!')

    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Мут')
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Пользователь замучен!", description="**{0}** замучен пользователем **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=0xff00f6)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Мой ответ помог?

Comment: пасс контекс это старая функция, ее можно не изпользовать
а вообще, можно ли сделать, чтобы бот смотрел не права роли человека, а именно его роль? где именно она стоит по списку?

Comment: @ReGGeN не знаю... но мне  кажется, вам и этого достаточно. можете поставить галочку)

Comment: я поставлю, но если тебе не сложно, можешь помочь с кодом? я проредачу вопрос, добавлю туда код

Comment: могу. галочку надеюсь умеешь ставить)

Answer (score -1):

Можно даже не усложнять. Просто поставить роль бота, ниже чем роль Модератора.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]